# Как пишутся названия публикуемых списков/рейтингов от авторитетных организаций/изданий?

Tags: прописная-строчная, словосочетания

"Грамота.ру" рекомендует, например, в словосочетании *Список Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО* писать с прописной первые два слова: "Список" и "Всемирного" (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201731)). Другая рекомендация — писать с прописной *Список самых богатых людей мира по версии журнала «Форбс»* (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=288383)). Еще одна рекомендация — в словосочетании *Книга рекордов Гиннесса* писать слово "Книга" с прописной (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Тогда верно ли, что написание как минимум первого слова с прописной распространяется и на другие международные списки/рейтинги от каких-либо организаций? Какое вообще правило тут применимо? Например, правильно ли: *Глобальный список миллиардеров Forbes 2019*, *Список 200 лучших романов по версии BBC*, *Список 250 самых высокооценённых фильмов всех времён по версии IMDb*?..

Answer (score 1):

Если вы дословно воспроизводите название этого списка в том виде, в котором он представлен в оригинальном СМИ, то, конечно, правильно будет написать название с прописной буквы. Если же вы как-то перефразириуете название, то нужды в прописной букве уже не будет.

"Список Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО" имеет в себе два названия: собственно, сам "Список..." и "Всемирное...", так что логично, что тут две прописных буквы.

"Книга рекордов Гиннесса" так и называется: "Книга...", поэтому пишется с прописной. Гиннесс — фамилия, тоже с прописной.

> Тогда верно ли, что написание как минимум первого слова с прописной
> распространяется и на другие международные списки/рейтинги от
> каких-либо организаций?

Только в тех случаях, когда вы дословно воспроизводите название списков/рейтингов.